# Multiple tableview issue

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have implemented a view controller with a table view controll called ligatable. This table view has its delegate in a table view controller called ligaViewController.h. Table view control has implemented one prototype cell, that has set ligaCell.h controller. Here are the details:

```
competicionViewController.h

#import "ligaViewController.h"

@interface CompeticionViewController : UIViewController 
{

    IBOutlet UITableView *ligaTable;
    ligaViewController *ligaController;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *ligaTable;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ligaViewController *ligaController;

competicionViewController.h

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
...

 ligaController = [[ligaViewController alloc] init];

    [ligaTable setDelegate:ligaController];
    [ligaTable setDataSource:ligaController];

....
```

And the delegate method in ligaViewController:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        ligaCell *cell = [self.tableView
                          dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"posicion"];


        NSDictionary *posicion = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary: [ligaArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        cell.posicion.text = [posicion valueForKey:@"posicion"];

        cell.PJ.text = [posicion valueForKey:@"pj"];

        cell.PG.text = [posicion valueForKey:@"pg"];

        cell.PP.text = [posicion valueForKey:@"pp"];

        cell.PF.text = [posicion valueForKey:@"favor"];

        cell.PC.text = [posicion valueForKey:@"contra"];

        return cell;

}
```

It is currently giving me this error:

```
terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use -

```
ligaCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"posicion"];
if (cell == nil)
{ 
    cell = [[[ligaCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CustomCellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. By the way, do you have an example of initWithIdentifier: method to be implemented in ligaCell?

Comment: Checkout this blog, it will help you - http://jainmarket.blogspot.in/2009/05/creating-custom-table-view-cell.html